# Objective-C how do I "rotate" an "angular" value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, math

Ok, I agree, my math is rusty and it **stinks** and my brain is completely empty right now.

I have a function that delivers me angles in the range of 0 to 360 degrees (or 0 to 2PI if you prefer). When I use this function with the gyroscope data, I see that when it says the device is 270 degrees, it is in fact zero degrees. So, if I rotate it from 270 to 360, I need the angles to be varying from 0 to 90.

How do I convert this?

If I simply subtract 270 degrees from the values coming, I will end with negative angles and I don't want that. What I need is to shift the values so:

```
270 degrees... will become zero,
360 (=0)... will become 90,
90 will be 180 and
180 will be 270.
```

How do I shift that mathematically speaking.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double trans(double ang) { 
  ang+=270; 
  return (ang>=360)?ang-360:ang; 
}
```

Or in one step:

```
double trans(double ang) {
 return (ang>=90)?ang-90:ang+270;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also walk along modulo lane. The basic trick is to keep degrees positive and then use the modulo, so the remainder of a division. Of course rotating 270 degree in one direction is the same as rotating 90 degrees in the other direction, so my implementation looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger) convertAngle:(NSInteger)oldAngle {
  NSInteger newAngle = oldAngle + 90;
  return newAngle%360;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
- (NSInteger)adjustedDegrees:(NSInteger)degrees {
    return ((degrees - 270) % 360);
}
```

You can use what's called modular arithmetic, which does your subtraction, then takes the *positive remainder after dividing by 360*.

Comment: For negative numbers `%` is not guaranteed to return a positive number.  It's implementation dependent.

Comment: You are right, but the answer reminds me of CS class. Standard answer to C questions: "that is compiler dependent". ;-D

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
float angle = gyroscopeValue;
angle += 90;
if(angle == 360)
    angle = 90;
if(angle == 270)
    angle =0;
```